# UWP / C# Rotating BMP

Tags: c#, image, rotation, uwp, bmp

The question seems to be asked already, however I cannot find a relevant answer.

I am loading a BMP image to memory in a UWP app, and I would like to rotate it by either 90, 180 or 270, but I just cannot find the way to do this.

The imgSource.rotate() does not seem to exist anymore
The RotateTransform works with xaml
....

Could anyone add the missing code by a chance please?

```
public async Task LoadImage()
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("test.bmp");
        using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            bitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
            var imgSource = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight);

            // Code to rotate image by 180 to be added

            bitmap.CopyToBuffer(imgSource.PixelBuffer);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The RotateTransform works with xaml

As you known, [`RotateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242932) is for rotate transform in uwp app XAML. A `RotateTransform` is defined by an [Angle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.rotatetransform.angle) that rotates an object through an arc around the point CenterX, CenterY. But a transform is typically used to fill the [`UIElement.RenderTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.rendertransform) property, so if you load the image source to an [`ImageControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx), you can rotate the `ImageControl` since it is a `UIElement`. For example, if we have `ImageControl` as follows:

```
<Image x:Name="PreviewImage" Height="400" Width="300" AutomationProperties.Name="Preview of the image"  Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

We can simply rotate it by `angle` property by code as:

```
RotateTransform m_transform = new RotateTransform(); 
PreviewImage.RenderTransform = m_transform;
m_transform.Angle = 180;
```

If you need rotate an image file not a `UIElement`, you may need to decode the image file as what you already did and then encode the file with setting the [`BitmapTransform.Rotation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.rotation.aspx) property. Code as follows:

```
  double m_scaleFactor;
  private async void btnrotatefile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("test.bmp"); 
      using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite),
                                         memStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
      {
          BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream); 
          uint originalWidth = decoder.PixelWidth;
          uint originalHeight = decoder.PixelHeight;
          BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(memStream, decoder);
          if (m_scaleFactor != 1.0)
          {
              encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = (uint)(originalWidth * m_scaleFactor);
              encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = (uint)(originalHeight * m_scaleFactor);
              encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;
          }

         //Rotate 180
          encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
          await encoder.FlushAsync(); 
          memStream.Seek(0);
          fileStream.Seek(0);
          fileStream.Size = 0;
          await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(memStream, fileStream);
      }
  }
```

More features about the image file rotation you can use other APIS under [`Windows.Graphics.Imaging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.aspx)  namespace. And the scenario 2 of [SimpleImaging](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleImaging)  official sample provides a complete sample about image rotation you can reference.

Comment: This is fantastic, works as expected. Indeed scenario 2 was the one needed. Thank you so much Sunteen.

Comment: This solution is great! However, do you have any idea how it can be done only with XAML definitions and bindings? (You may see more details in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53176985/997940)