# UWP - Rotating an Image while keeping it aligned to the grid, using XAML only

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Using [Windows Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio), I created a (mostly auto-generated) sample UWP application, which shows a bunch of Images within a GridView.

In order to rotate them, I've used the following xaml - note `RenderTransform` block which I've added, and the comments within that scope:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
    <GridView
        x:Name="ImagesGridView"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source}"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        Padding="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:SampleImage">
                <Image
                    x:Name="galleryImage"
                    Style="{StaticResource ThumbnailImageStyle}"
                    Source="{x:Bind Source}"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind Name}">
                    <Image.RenderTransform> <!-- That's the part which I've added, on top of the auto-generated xaml -->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="114" CenterY="114" /> <!-- because the ThumbnailImageStyle defines width and height as 228 -->
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

So that worked fine - until I tried non-square photos.
At this stage, the result was that the image itself would sometimes show outside of its container within the grid:

[image: note the first two images' locations, compared to where their grid item container actually is]

I've tried:

- To use different values for the CenterX and CenterY fields (according to the grid's item size, according to the original image size, or just ["0.5, 0.5"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4132307/997940)), but that didn't solve the case.
- To use `Image.LayoutTransform` ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909494/997940)), but it doesn't seem to be available in a Universal Application (or perhaps I'm missing some reference?).
- Noticed that when I click on the problematic images, they will suddenly move back to their expected location within the grid (and also sometimes the rotation will be gone, so its back to the original image).

Eventually, I solved it by rotating the image in the code-behind ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42060749/997940)), before adding it to the binded source of the GridView - but shouldn't there be a proper way to achieve that just by using the xaml itself?

Comment: The Windows Community Toolkit has an alternate LayoutTransform control documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/LayoutTransformControl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So that worked fine - until I tried non-square photos. At this stage, the result was that the image itself would sometimes show outside of its container within the grid:

If u want the image will rotate with center and it will not display outside `GridView`. you could set [`RenderTransformOrigin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.rendertransformorigin) property.

```
<Image Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
Source="{Binding}">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <!-- That's the part which I've added, on top of the auto-generated xaml -->
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        <!-- because the ThumbnailImageStyle defines width and height as 228 -->
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

[image]

Update
When the `GridView` item clicked, the default Pressed `visual` statue will make the content of gridview  re-layout. Currently, there is a workaround that use `GridViewItemExpanded` style.

```
<GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemExpanded}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have read better into the online documentation 

Comment: On second thought, that doesn't fully solve my problem.. because when I press the images, they go back to their original orientation, without any rotation. What am I missing here?

Comment: I saw it, when the GridView Item clicked, the default `Pressed` visual statue will be invoke the content of gridview will be re-layout. currently, there is a workaround that use  `GridViewItemExpanded` style.

Comment: Could you please explain about what it is and how to use it? (can edit the original answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183245/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-yoav-feuerstein).

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't get to try it yet - but I will soon. Will comment if there are any problems :)